# What does "maintenance mode" for Boost mean?

Tags: c++, boost

For example, I've seen this on a `boost.heap` [issue](https://github.com/boostorg/heap/issues/24):

> boost.heap is in maintenance mode. but i'm more than happy to integrate PRs

What does maintenance mode mean? Does it mean it's deprecated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode) (wikipedia article):

> In the world of software development, maintenance mode refers to a
> point in a computer program's life when it has reached all of its
> goals and is generally considered to be "complete" and bug-free. The
> term can also refer to the point in a software product's evolution
> when it is no longer competitive with other products or current with
> regard to the technology environment it operates within. In both
> cases, continued development is deemed unnecessary or ill-advised, but
> occasional bug fixes and security patches are still issued, hence the
> term maintenance mode. Maintenance mode often transitions to
> abandonware.
>
> Sometimes, when a popular free software project undergoes a major
> overhaul, the pre-overhaul version is kept active and put into
> maintenance mode because it will still be widely used in production
> for the foreseeable future.

In the boost heap case most likely it means that the library is considered feature complete and bug free and the authors are not working on it anymore, but they will accept PRs from the community. It doesn't mean it's "deprecated"

Comment: I saw this page before posting my question.  I think I cannot mark an answer is right that is quoting a page that gives two different answers (basically that either the code is now perfected, or that it is no longer competitive).

Comment: @SwissFrank why not? Both are valid reasons why a library could be maintenance mode.

Comment: @SwissFrank of course it's your prerogative to give or not to give the accepted tick. For me, I don't see a contradictions. You can read it as: It's "perfect" for how it was designed but the design is now "outdated" and there is no intention on overhauling the product on a new design. It works as intended, but there is a better new way to achieve the same thing. You can also read it two different reasons: for some products the answer is "it's perfect" for other products the answer is "it's outdated". Also the quote never says "perfect", it says "complete".

Comment: @SwissFrank "maintenance mode" describes the amount of attention that a project is getting.  It does **not** describe **why** it is getting that amount of attention.

Comment: To clarify I am asking what this means in Boost specifically.  You are not answering that.  Instead you are pointing me to a definition that could mean either of two opposite things.  If this term has no particular meaning in the world of Boost, THAT would be an answer (especially with a citation!).

Comment: I answered that in the last paragraph.

Comment: *I answered that in the last paragraph.* -- apologies, I must have overlooked that, now accepting